# how to add two textfiled and one button in electron Dialog box

Tags: javascript, dialog, electron, textfield

I have called dialog with sample message and button field to popup but additionally i need to include two textfield in same dialog box but i couldn't make it.

Can anyone solve my problem by suitable answer.

**here my sample code in Electron Application:**

```
dialog.showMessageBox({ message: "Hello There :-)",
        buttons: ["OK"] });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Electron doesn't support prompt dialogs.](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/472) Don't [window.prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) neither.

One solution could be to use [sweetalert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2) or some other npm package in the renderer process. If you need to call it from the main process, you can use [ipcMain](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) to send it to the renderer.

**(Untested) Example**

Main process:

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')

let promptHandler

ipcMain.on('prompt-handler-registered', event => promptHandler = event.sender)

// Create Promise to make it easier to get the promptHandler
const getPromptHandler = new Promise((resolve) => {
  const watcher = setInterval(() => {
    // You'll probably want to set a timeout here
    if (!promptHandler) return

    resolve(promptHandler)
    clearInterval(watcher)
  }, 200)
})

...

// When you want to prompt the user
getPromptHandler
  .then(ph => ph.send('display-prompt', {
      title: 'Whats your name?',
      ...
    })
  )
```

Renderer process:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
const swal = require('sweetalert2')

function displayPrompt(data) {
  swal({
    title: data.title,
    input: 'text',
  })
}

ipcRenderer.send('prompt-handler-registered')

ipcRenderer.on('display-prompt', displayPrompt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own dialog system to show a dialog with two text fields. The [dialog API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md) in Electron does not support customization dialogs to that degree.

Answer (score -1):

**Try electron-prompt.**

First

> npm install electron-prompt

Here a basic example where I display a dialog box asking for a password to access the app else it closes :

Main.js file

```
const { app, BrowserWindow  } = require('electron')
const prompt = require('electron-prompt')

const createWindow = () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    frame:false,
    icon:'src/js/logo.png',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  mainWindow.maximize();
  mainWindow.loadFile('src/index.html')
  //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.on('ready', () => {
  prompt({
    title: 'Authentication',
    label: 'Enter Password:',
    inputAttrs: {
      type: 'text'
    },
    type: 'input'
  })
    .then((password) => {
      if (password === '123') {
        createWindow();
      } else {
        app.quit();
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: First contribution lol, we are good now i hope

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35687284)